# What does stripUnknown in JOI validation does?

Tags: express, hapi.js, joi

The Documentaion of JOI says that,

**response.options**
Options to pass to joi during validation. Useful to set global options such as stripUnknown or abortEarly. If a custom validation function is defined via schema or status then options can an arbitrary object that will be passed to this function as the second argument.

It is not clear that what it does.

```
const joi = require('joi');

joi.validate(object, schema, {stripUnknown:true}, callback);
```

Can someone tell me what does stripUnknown does?

Answer (score 3):

```
        validate: {
            payload: Joi.object({
                start: Joi.string().min(1).max(4),
                end: Joi.date().required()
            }).options({ stripUnknown: true, abortEarly: false })
        }
```

In the above example, stripUnknown is set to true that it will not complain if your payload has any other keys other than start and end. By default stripUnknown is false.

Answer (score 1):

As of Joi 17, there are 2 complimentary properties:

- `allowUnknown` which ignores properties of your object being validated, that are not defined in your schema
- `stripUnknown` which removes properties that are not a part of your schema

For example, if your schema is as follows:

```
Joi.object({
  min: Joi.number().required(),
  max: Joi.number().required()
}).options({ allowUnknown: true })
```

If you pass through `{ min: 1, max: 2, unknown: "unknown" }` on `validate` then you will receive an object back which is the same as the input as it is allowing properties that your schema does not know about. If you did not set this or set it to false (its default value) then you would receive a validation error.

If we update your schema to include the use of `stripUnknown`:

```
Joi.object({
  min: Joi.number().required(),
  max: Joi.number().required()
}).options({ allowUnknown: true, stripUnknown: true })
```

If you pass through `{ min: 1, max: 2, unknown: "unknown" }` on `validate` then you will receive an object back which is `{ min: 1, max: 2 }` as it has stripped any properties that the schema does not know about.

As of today I am facing a separate issue with the above behaviour not working when you use the validation extension function `.unknown()` therefore will be avoiding that functionality and using the above.